# `expected reference, found integral variable` in accessing a value from BTreeMap

Tags: rust

I'm trying to retrieve a key from a `BTreeMap` and manipulate it in subsequent code.

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: BTreeMap<u64, u64> = BTreeMap::new();
    map.entry(0).or_insert(0);

    // It seems like this should work:
    let y = map[0] + 1;  // expected reference, found integral variable

    // Other things I've tried:
    let value_at_0 = map[0];  // expected reference, found integral variable
    let ref value_at_0 = map[0];  // expected reference, found integral variable
    let y = value_at_0 + 1;

    let y = (&map[0]) + 1;  // expected reference, found integral variable
    let y = (&mut map[0]) + 1;  // binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&mut u64`
    let y = (*map[0]) + 1;  // type `u64` cannot be dereferenced
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

The error is particularly confusing, since I would think an integral variable would be *precisely* the kind of thing you could add `1` to.

To show what I would like this code to do, here is how this would be implemented in Python:

```py
>>> map = {}
>>> map.setdefault(0, 0)
0
>>> y = map[0] + 1
>>> print(y)
1
```

For SEO purposes, since my Googling failed, the originating error in somewhat more complex code is `expected reference, found u64`

For reference, the full compilation error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> ./map_weirdness.rs:8:15
  |
8 |       let y = map[0] + 1;  // expected reference, found integral variable
  |               ^^^^^^ expected reference, found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `&u64`
  = note:    found type `{integer}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in what was being *passed* to `[]`, though the error highlighted the whole `map[0]`, suggesting that the error was in the type of the *value* of `map[0]` when it was actually in computing the value. The correct implementation needs to pass a reference to `[]` as follows:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: BTreeMap<u64, u64> = BTreeMap::new();
    map.entry(0).or_insert(0);

    let y = map[&0] + 1;
    println!("{}", y);
}
```